# Dagger2 Singletone is null

Tags: android, dagger-2

I use Dagger2, and sometimes my singletons are null, but can't find out how can it happens.

I have a singletone like this:

```
@Singleton
public class WebViewManager {
    private static final Object lock = new Object();
    protected ArrayList<WebContentPartView> webViews;
    private WebView mWebView;
@Inject
public WebViewManager(){}
```

and I inject it into my Fragment's at onCreate().

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Logger.logFragment(this);
    IndexApplication.getAppComponent().inject(this);
    setRetainInstance(false);
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    velocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
}
```

and at when I call one of my singletone's method it throws NPE. I can't reproduce it, but I can see it at Crashlytics.
I need to call this method when the user swipes away from the fragment. At the Activity I store this fragment as a WeakReference.
When the user swipes away, or leave the Activity at first I check the reference, if it isn't null, I get the Fragment from the reference, and if it isn't null also, I call the WebViewManager's method to load empty data into the Fragment's WebViews (to stop media). And at this point some of my users get NPE.

I register my Fragment to AppComponent, that I instantiate at my Application class.

---

An **update** for this issue. Not the exactly the same issue, but when I try to inject my launcher Activity into AppComponent (I instantiate at Application's onCreate()) I get this exception:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
>   Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aff.index.main/com.aff.index.index.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method

I got this error when Dagger try to provide SharedPreferences.
Initialize Dagger at Application's onCreate():

```
                    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent
                        .builder()
                        .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                        .build();
```

AppModule and providing Application, Context and SharedPreferences:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
private final IndexApplication indexApplication;

public AppModule(IndexApplication application) {
    this.indexApplication = application;
}

@Provides
IndexApplication indexApplication() {
    return indexApplication;
}

@Provides
Context provideContext() {
    return indexApplication.getApplicationContext();
}

@Provides
SharedPreferences provideSharedPreferences(IndexApplication application) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
}
```

Here is the full stack trace:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aff.index.main/com.aff.index.index.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2762)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2848)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1552)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6334)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>   Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method
>          at dagger.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:48)
>          at com.aff.index.dagger.AppModule_IndexApplicationFactory.get(AppModule_IndexApplicationFactory.java:22)
>          at com.aff.index.dagger.AppModule_IndexApplicationFactory.get(AppModule_IndexApplicationFactory.java:8)
>          at com.aff.index.dagger.AppModule_ProvideSharedPreferencesFactory.get(AppModule_ProvideSharedPreferencesFactory.java:30)
>          at com.aff.index.dagger.AppModule_ProvideSharedPreferencesFactory.get(AppModule_ProvideSharedPreferencesFactory.java:10)
>          at com.aff.index.index.SplashActivity_MembersInjector.injectMembers(SplashActivity_MembersInjector.java:135)
>          at com.aff.index.index.SplashActivity_MembersInjector.injectMembers(SplashActivity_MembersInjector.java:20)
>          at com.aff.index.dagger.DaggerAppComponent.inject(DaggerAppComponent.java:2583)
>          at com.aff.index.index.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:185)
>          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6743)
>          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2715)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2848)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1552)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6334)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: Dagger will never inject `null` into your fragment. Double check your code and make sure you don't call any methods _before_ `onCreate`. If you can't find your problem, please include all the relevant code (the activity where it accesses / loads the fragment, the crashing line of code, etc..)

Comment: Thanks. So you mean I try to call the WebViewManager's method before onCreate() called and Dagger would able to instantiate it?

Comment: try providing `return indexApplication;` as the `appContext`